# Filter_var returns false if validating failed on any of the elements in array?

Tags: php

How can I make filter_var to return false if validating failed on any of the elements in array?

```
$ids = array(6,3,5,8);

$result = filter_var($ids, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array('min_range' => 4),
    'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
    )
);

var_dump($result);
/* returns
array(4) { [0]=> int(6) [1]=> bool(false) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(8) } 
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `filter_var()` can't be made to return `false` when arrays are involved; you'd have to add another condition:

```
if (in_array(false, $result, true)) {
    // one or more entries failed the filter
}
```

Make sure to have `true` as the last argument to `in_array()`, otherwise `0` would also be considered `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator:

```
$result = in_array(false, $result) ? false : true;
```

If boolean false is in your array (by checking with the in_array() function, assign boolean false to $result, otherwise assign true (or return the $result) to save the array.

**Edit:**

In response to others, in shorthand, to return true or false, whether the array has passed or not, simply use

```
$result = in_array(false, $result);
```

Comment: no need to use a ternary operator: `in_array` returns already a boolean. You have to do: `$result = !in_array(false, $result);`

Comment: @antoox Thats correct as well! I only added the ternary if the $result was fine, whether the user would prefer to return the filtered array, or boolean true :)

Comment: @PhilCross I wanted filter_var() to return false directly. But thanx anyway.